# Windows FileDialog: Open History Dropdown Box with a Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: windows, openfiledialog, qfiledialog

When you open a OpenFileDialog, the name input field has a dropdown combo box, that shows the last recent file histroy for the given file extension.
Is there a keyboard shortcut to open that dropdown list? I tried Space, CrsrDn, F4 - none worked for me. (I'm using Qt - QFileDialog, btw. but I think it's just a wrapper around the Windows API).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>F4</kbd> opens the address combo. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> opens the filename combo when it has keyboard focus.